# What are Python's equivalent of Javascript's reduce(), map(), and filter()?

Tags: javascript, python

What are Python's equivalent of the following (Javascript):

```
function wordParts (currentPart, lastPart) {
    return currentPart+lastPart;
}

word = ['Che', 'mis', 'try'];
console.log(word.reduce(wordParts))
```

and this:

```
var places = [
    {name: 'New York City', state: 'New York'},
    {name: 'Oklahoma City', state: 'Oklahoma'},
    {name: 'Albany', state: 'New York'},
    {name: 'Long Island', state: 'New York'},
]

var newYork = places.filter(function(x) { return x.state === 'New York'})
console.log(newYork)
```

lastly, this:

```
function greeting(name) {
    console.log('Hello ' + name + '. How are you today?');
}
names = ['Abby', 'Cabby', 'Babby', 'Mabby'];

var greet = names.map(greeting)
```

Thanks all!

Comment: `reduce`, `map`, and `filter` :P unless you're in python3, in which case it's `functools.reduce` See here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: Same naming I presume with being built-in functions.

Comment: Your last example is not the idiomatic/correct use of `Array.prototype.map`; you should instead use `Array.prototype.forEach` or `;[].forEach.call`

Comment: Giant warning on the answers, here: list comprehensions and generators seem to be favored over `map` and `filter`, these days. So it looks like `[mutate(x) for x in list if x > 10]`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

They are all similar, lamdba functions are often passed as a parameter to these functions in Python.

Reduce:

```
 >>> from functools import reduce
 >>> reduce((lambda x, y: x + y), [1, 2, 3, 4])
 10
```

Filter:

```
>>> list(filter((lambda x: x < 0), range(-10,5)))
[-10, -9, -8, -7, - 6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1]
```

Map:

```
>>> list(map((lambda x: x **2), [1,2,3,4]))
[1,4,9,16]
```

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)

Comment: This is sort of what I'm looking for, but is it possible to include a function inside lambda?

Comment: Yes it is.  eg.   doublelength = lambda x: len(x)*2

Answer (score 7):

It is worth noting that this question has been answered at face value above with the accepted answer, but as @David Ehrmann mentioned in a comment in the question, it is preferred to use comprehensions instead of `map` and `filter`.

Why is that? As stated in "Effective Python, 2nd Edition" by Brett Slatkin pg. 108, "Unless you're applying a single-argument function, list comprehensions are also clearer than the `map` built-in function for simple cases. `map` requires the creation of a `lambda` function for the computation, which is visually noisy." I would add the same goes for `filter`.

e.g. let's say I want to map and filter over a list to return the square of the items in the list, but only the even ones (this is an example from the book).

Using the accepted answer's method of using lambdas:

```py
arr = [1,2,3,4]
even_squares = list(map(lambda x: x**2, filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, arr)))
print(even_squares) # [4, 16]
```

Using comprehensions:

```py
arr = [1,2,3,4]
even_squares = [x**2 for x in arr if x%2 == 0]
print(even_squares) # [4, 16]
```

So, along with others, I would advise using comprehensions instead of `map` and `filter`. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map) dives into it even further.

As far as `reduce` goes, `functools.reduce` still seems like the proper option.

Answer (score 3):

```
reduce(function, iterable[, initializer])

filter(function, iterable)

map(function, iterable, ...)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Answer (score 0):

The first is:

```
from functools import *
def wordParts (currentPart, lastPart):
    return currentPart+lastPart;


word = ['Che', 'mis', 'try']
print(reduce(wordParts, word))
```