# How to find a binary number all 1s positions use bit manipulation?

Tags: python, algorithm, bit-manipulation

For example, I have a number 210 or 11010010 in binary, the 2nd 5th 7th and 8th position is 1, so the result is [2, 5, 7, 8].

What is the fastest way to find that?

Comment: Please pick *one* programming language, the one you're working with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Python's equivalent of Javascript's reduce(), map(), and filter()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31127824/what-are-pythons-equivalent-of-javascripts-reduce-map-and-filter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Convert the number to binary:

   ```
   >>> format(210, 'b')
   '11010010'
   ```
2. Use a list comprehension and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to find the indices of the 1s:

   ```
   >>> [i for i, digit in enumerate(reversed('11010010'), 1) if digit == '1'] 
   [2, 5, 7, 8]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over your binary number to get the result.

```
a=format(210, 'b')
x=[]
for i in range(0,len(a)):
    if a[i] == '1':
        x.append(i+1)
```

1 position is [1, 2, 4, 7]

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to precompute all combinations (only 256 of them) by whatever method, and store in a list (of lists).

---

You can build the list by appending 1 to all entries, then 2 to every other entries, then 3 to every fourth entries, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A solution in C++.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n=10;
    int counter=1;
    while(n)
    {
        if(n&1==1)
        {
            cout<<counter<<" ";
        }
         n=n>>1;
        counter++;
    }

}
```

Read a bit about bitwise shift and & operator, to understand the solution properly.